# Elastic search relevance search for parent-child relation types

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am working with elastic search and I need to build a relevance search query apart from my requirement but I am stuck on this.

Please  see my insertion part, I have parent-child mapping for my records

PUT  /myindex

> {   "mappings": {
>       "my_registration": {},
>       "my_specialities": {
>         "_parent": {
>           "type": "my_registration"
>         }
>       }   } }

PUT myindex/my_registration/100

> {
>               "Pid": "100",
>               "Name": "name1",
>               "Age": "28" }

PUT myindex/my_registration/200

> {
>               "Pid": "200",
>               "Name": "name2",
>               "Age": "28" }

PUT myindex/my_registration/300

> {
>               "Pid": "300",
>               "Name": "name3",
>               "Age": "28" }

PUT myindex/my_specialities/1?parent=100

> {     "Pid": "100",   "speciality_name": "Orthopedic Surgeon"
>
> }

PUT myindex/my_specialities/2?parent=200

> {     "Pid": "200",   "speciality_name": "Orthopedic"
>
> }

PUT myindex/my_specialities/3?parent=300

> {     "Pid": "300",   "speciality_name": "Surgeon"
>
> }

**Please my scenario**

1- I need to search speciality_name as Orthopedic Surgeon

2- I need to search speciality_name as Surgeon

3- I need to search speciality_name as Orthopedic

4- I need to search speciality_name as Orth etc

5- I need to search speciality_name as Orthop

6- I need to search speciality_name as Orthoepdic

See my bellow sample query, I am expecting to get the results for all above cases (need to return records with a relevance score, I am getting the null result for case 4 and 5).

/myindex/my_registration/_search

> {     "query": {      "bool": {           "must": [{
>                 "has_child": {
>                     "type": "my_specialities",
>                     "query": {
>                         "fuzzy": {
>                             "speciality_name": {
>                                 "value": "Orthop",
>                                 "boost": 1.0,
>                                 "fuzziness": 2,
>                                 "prefix_length": 0,
>                                 "max_expansions": 100
>                             }
>                         }
>                     },
>                     "inner_hits": {}
>                 }           }]      }   } }

Please note that here I need to return the result form type my_registration but searching is applying in type my_specialities.

Any suggession please, Thanks in advance and sorry for lengthy question  :)

Comment: Have you tried with a simple match query instead of the fuzzy one?

Comment: see the last part of the question, I am applying the fuzzy query

Comment: I saw that. Thats the reason why I'm asking if you tried the match query. For that kind of search it should work fine.

Comment: I am Sorry, simple match query is also not suitable for me. I need fuzzy feature also

Comment: I have updated my question and added case 6

Answer (score 0):

You are fixing the fuzziness to 2, according to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) the fuzziness is the Levenshtein edit distance, that means that it will match terms that at maximum needs to change two letters to match the value in the query.

If you search for Orthop you need al least to add 4 characters to match the closest one (Orthopedic). Thats the reason why you are getting null. You can rise the fuzinness value or try leavig it as auto.

Comment: Just for the record, raising the fuzziness beyond 2 is not advised. If you need to find `Orthopedic` when searching for `Orthop`, you either need to use the `prefix` query or leverage edge-ngrams at indexing time.